# jquery-ui autocomplete works locally not on heroku

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, heroku, sinatra, local

I am using jquery-ui's autocomplete on two input fields of an HTML form in a Sinatra app. They work on my local machine but not on Heroku. Jquery-ui's datepicker works on this same page, so I know the jquery and jquery-ui javascript files are being loaded correctly. Also, I can see that the variable that I am using as the source for the autocomplete is actually getting populated from the database. There are no console errors as well.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="/add-event" method="post">
     Date: <input id="datepicker" class="required" type="text" maxlength="50" name="date" /><br />
     Headliner: <input id="headliner" class="required" type="text" maxlength="50" name="headliner" /><br />
     Venue: <input id="venue" class="required" type="text" maxlength="50" name="venue_name" /><br />
</form>
```

There are some other fields in the form, but they don't play a part in any of this.

Here's the Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var artist_names = [<%= @artist_names %>];
    var venue_names = [<%= @venue_names %>];

    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Set button disabled
        $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var submitForm = function(date, headliner, venue) {

            //If form is validated enable form

            if ((date != "") && ($.inArray(headliner, artist_names) != -1) && ($.inArray(venue, venue_names) != -1)) 
                {
                    $("input:submit#event").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("input:submit#event").attr("disabled", true);
                }

            $('#typing').html(date+headliner + venue);
        }

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { submitForm(this.value, $('#headliner').val(), $('#venue').val()) }
        });

        $("#headliner").autocomplete({
            source: artist_names,
            select: function(event, ui) { 
                submitForm($('#datepicker').val(), ui.item.value, $('#venue').val()); 
                $('#add-artist').empty();
                }
        });

        $("#venue").autocomplete({
            source: venue_names,
            select: function(event, ui) { 
                submitForm($('#datepicker').val(), $('#headliner').val(), ui.item.value); 
                $('#add-venue').empty(); 
                }
        });

        //Append a change event listener to you inputs
        $('#headliner').keyup(function() {
            var val = $('#headliner').val();
            if ($.inArray(val, artist_names) == -1) 
            {   
                if (val=="") 
                {
                    $('#add-artist').empty();
                }
                else 
                {
                    $('#add-artist').html("<strong>" + val + "</strong> isn't in our database. you must first add a profile for them to add this event!<br /><form action='/add-artist-event' method='post'><br />Artist Name: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='artist_name' value='" + val +"' /><br /> Website: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='artist_website' /><br /> Facebook: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='artist_facebook' /><br />Twitter: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='artist_twitter' /><br />Soundcloud: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='artist_soundcloud' /><br />Bandcamp: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='artist_bandcamp' /><br /><button type='button' id='add-artist-button' onclick='addNewArtist();'>Add New Artist!</button></form><br /><br />" );
                }
                $("input:submit#event").attr("disabled", true);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#add-artist').empty();
                submitForm($('#datepicker').val(), $('#headliner').val(), $('#venue').val()); 
            }

        });

        $('#venue').keyup(function() {
            var val = $('#venue').val();
            if ($.inArray(val, venue_names) == -1) 
            {   
                if (val=="") 
                {
                    $('#add-venue').empty();
                }
                else 
                {
                    $('#add-venue').html("<strong>" + val + "</strong>" + " is not in our database. you must first add a profile for this venue to add this event!<br /><form action='/add-venue-event' method='post'><br />Venue Name: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_name' value='" + val +"'/><br />Address: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_address' /><br />City: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_city' /><br />State: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_state' /><br />Zip: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_zip' /><br />Phone: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_phone' /><br /> Website: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_website' /><br /> Facebook: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_facebook' /><br />Twitter: <input type='text' maxlength='50' name='venue_twitter' /><br /><button type='button' id='add-venue-button' onclick='addNewVenue();'>Add New Venue!</button> </form><br /><br />");
                }
                $("input:submit#event").attr("disabled", true);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#add-venue').empty();
                submitForm($('#datepicker').val(), $('#headliner').val(), $('#venue').val()); 
            }

        });


    });

    var addNewArtist = function() { 
            $.post('/add-event/new-artist', {

                artist_name: $(':input[name="artist_name"]').val(),
                website: $(':input[name="artist_website"]').val(),
                facebook: $(':input[name="artist_facebook"]').val(),
                twitter: $(':input[name="artist_twitter"]').val(),
                soundcloud: $(':input[name="artist_soundcloud"]').val(),
                bandcamp: $(':input[name="artist_bandcamp"]').val()

            },

            function(output) {

                artist_names = output.split(',');

                $('#add-artist').html(output);
                $('#headliner').autocomplete("option", { source: artist_names });
            });
        };

    var addNewVenue = function() { 
            $.post('/add-event/new-venue', {

                venue_name: $(':input[name="venue_name"]').val(),
                street_address: $(':input[name="venue_address"]').val(),
                city: $(':input[name="venue_city"]').val(),
                state: $(':input[name="venue_state"]').val(),
                zip: $(':input[name="venue_zip"]').val(),
                phone: $(':input[name="venue_phone"]').val(),
                email: $(':input[name="venue_email"]').val(),
                website: $(':input[name="venue_website"]').val(),
                facebook: $(':input[name="venue_facebook"]').val(),
                twitter: $(':input[name="venue_twitter"]').val()

            },

            function(output) { 

                venue_names = output.split(',');

                $('#add-venue').html(output);
                $('#venue').autocomplete("option", { source: venue_names });
            });
    };
</script>
```

I was hoping to avoid including all the javascript in the question, but I think it's best that I do. The only other piece is that when I "view source" in chrome I see the two variables are indeed getting populated with data:

```
var artist_names = [["'Bubonic Bear', "]];
var venue_names = [["'Electric Factory', "]];
```

---

### UPDATE

If I hardcode a list for the "headliner" field's autocomplete function, the autocomplete works.

```
$("#headliner").autocomplete({
            //source: artist_names,
            source: ["band1", "band2", "band3"],
            select: function(event, ui) { 
                submitForm($('#datepicker').val(), ui.item.value, $('#venue').val()); 
                $('#add-artist').empty();
                }
        });
```

I'm still not sure of the solution, it seems odd that a variable would be accessible in a local instance of the app and not on heroku. Anyway, I will add more if I figure out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how that would work anywhere. Your data sources:

```
var artist_names = [<%= @artist_names %>];
var venue_names  = [<%= @venue_names %>];
```

come out as:

```
var artist_names = [["'Bubonic Bear', "]];
var venue_names  = [["'Electric Factory', "]];
```

and that's not the right format for the jQuery-UI Autocomplete widget. The `source` option should be a simple array of strings when you're using an inlined source.

You should be inlining your arrays in JSON format:

```
var artist_names = <%= @artist_names.to_json %>;
var venue_names  = <%= @venue_names.to_json  %>;
```

and that should produce things like this:

```
var artist_names = ["Bubonic Bear"];
var venue_names  = ["Electric Factory"];
```

and the autocomplete widget will be happy with that.

You can play with this demo to see the difference:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Brb9p/

Comment: Hah, yea I'm not sure either. I was actually embarrassed to put that javascript up there, it's a mess. Anyway, you fixed it! Oh, so one question about your answer: you used <%=r @artist_names.to_json %>. I get a no method error "undefined method `r' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x1043942c0>". So I removed the r and it worked. What is the r? Thanks!

Comment: @wuliwong: The `r` is `raw` and means "don't HTML encode this", I guess that's Rails-specific and Sinatra doesn't have it (sorry, don't use Sinatra), I'll pull it out. And BTW, that JavaScript isn't that bad, like all code it could use a bit of cleaning but there's nothing horrifically bad about it and I've seen a lot worse.