# Autocomplete is not working in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, autocomplete

can anyone help me? i'm using rails4 and i have included autocomplete field which works in localhost but it's not working in heroku.

application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require jquery-ui
```

production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

routes.rb

```
get :autocomplete_customer_first_name, :on => :collection
```

application.js

```
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

controller

```
autocomplete  :customer, :first_name, :display_value => :first_name, :full => true
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems someone ran into a similar problem a while back, working on your machine but not Heroku. Check it out and let me know if this solution helps! [jquery-ui autocomplete works locally not on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827186/jquery-ui-autocomplete-works-locally-not-on-heroku)

Comment: no i didn't get the result..i have used the below code in my view:       <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'throwaway_customer', '',
          autocomplete_customer_first_name_savingsdeposits_path,
          :size => 25, :id_element => '#real_customer_id' %>

Comment: Okay - were you ever able to find an answer or resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, autocomplete option is working in heroku.
Just by re-arranging application.js file it works fine for me.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui  
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```